# Filter to match array exactly

Tags: rethinkdb

My documents contain an array, for example;

```
{
    "a": [ 2, 3 ],
    "id":  ...
}
```

I want to return only the documents for which `a` contains only the elements 2 and 3.

This is the simplest I've found yet;

```
r.table("t").filter(r.row('a').difference([2,3]).eq([]))
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice way to write the same function would be to use [`.isEmpty`](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/is_empty/) instead of `.eq([])`.

```
r.table("t")
 .filter(r.row('a').difference([2,3]).isEmpty())
```

This query is equivalent to the function you wrote.

That being said, your current query returns document where a has only 2 and/**or** 3. So, for example, a document with with `a: [2]` would get matched.

Example result set:

```
{
  "a": [ 2 ] ,
  "id":  "f60f0e43-a542-499f-9481-11372cc386c8"
} {
  "a": [ 2, 3 ] ,
  "id":  "c6ed9b4e-1399-47dd-a692-3db80df4143c"
}
```

That might be what you want, but if you only want documents where the `a` property is `[2, 3]` or `[3, 2]` exactly and contains no other elements, you might want to just use `.eq`:

```
r.table("t")
 .filter(r.row('a').eq([2,3]).or( r.row('a').eq([3, 2]) ))
```

Example result:

```
{
  "a": [ 2, 3 ] ,
  "id":  "c6ed9b4e-1399-47dd-a692-3db80df4143c"
}, {
  "a": [ 3, 2 ] ,
  "id":  "cb2b5fb6-7601-43b4-a0fd-4b6b8eb83438"
}
```

Comment: Hi Jorge. In this case the array would never have less than 2 elements, so I think it is the better solution as the .eq([2,3]) comparison requires the elements be ordered first. That said, I missed isEmpty() - thank you!

Comment: I updated my solution to match either `[2, 3]` or `[3, 2]` using just `eq`, so that the answer is more accurate.

Comment: Also, I took the time to answer your question and it seems I answered it correctly. I'd probably be best to mark it as answered :). Thanks!

Comment: The simple 'or' method makes the most sense. Sorry for the delay in marking your answer! I got side-tracked wondering whether a hash would be a better idea - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29725106/hash-uuids-without-requiring-ordering

Comment: Thanks! The hash idea is interesting, but personally it seems better to have the data in your database be very clear unless it saves a significant amount of time. Or not?